# Line not breaking correctly

Tags: css

I have an issue with line breaking. As you can see on screenshot 1, the text is fine but when the browser is pulled down (screenshot 2) the text breaks at random points rather than by word leaving a large white space. Ideally I'd like each word to drop when it needs to rather than all four words dropping at once.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

There is no padding or margin on this div. I have tried to the following word-wrap variables: normal, break-word, initial & inherit. I have also tried white-space: normal, no-wrap, pre, initial & inherit with no success.

HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="full bottom-position">

    <div class="half right">

        <?php if ( get_sub_field('client_name') ) : ?>

              <span class="left-span">Client:</span>
              <span class="right-span"><?php the_sub_field('client_name'); ?></span>

        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if ( get_sub_field('date') ) : ?>

              <span class="left-span">Date:</span>
              <span class="right-span"><?php the_sub_field('date'); ?></span>

        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if ( get_sub_field('version') ) : ?>

              <span class="left-span">Version:</span>
              <span class="right-span"><?php the_sub_field('version'); ?></span>

        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if ( get_sub_field('print') ) : ?>

              <span class="left-span">Print:</span>
              <span class="right-span"><a href="<?php the_sub_field('print'); ?>">Download presentation as PDF</a></span>

         <?php endif; ?>

     </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-span {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}

.right-span {
    width: 85%;
    float: left;
}

.half {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

This is an odd issue I've never come across before. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/qkt93epw/

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;`?.

Comment: Can you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) your code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar code posted.

Comment: @holloway Can you post HTML and not php code?

Comment: I have looked at your fiddle and I have to admit that its really confusing. When I resize the output window, the text `For more information please contact Managing Director ` IS dropping down on to the next line, word at a time.

Comment: @holloway The fiddle works for me too. Is it possible that &nbsp; is being used instead of a standard space?

Comment: Thanks for everyone taking a look. It turns out that the client had formatted the text incorrectly in the back end of Wordpress which was causing the error (not sure how). I simply removed their text completely and re-typed it to remove the formatting which now works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it? I have given my example worked for me.

You have give display block for span.

```
span {
    width:10px; /*You can change your width*/
    white-space: normal;
    display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<span>
    This is test. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.. This is test.
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it was a formatting error in the Wordpress backend.

Answer (score 0):

Client formatted the text incorrectly in the back end of Wordpress which was causing the error (not sure how). I simply removed their text completely and re-typed it to remove the formatting which now works. Thanks to @HiddenHobes for the heads up and everyone that tried to help.